# How can I use a switch case inside attrs of a component in styled components?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I am trying to work with variations of colors of an icon depending on the atributes of a component, but I don't know how to write it.

I was able to do it directly in an item of the styles, following the example:
[code example switch case styled component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8gQD.png)

But inside the attributes of a component, I can't write it, doesn't work, here is how I tried:
[code example switch case styled component through attrs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX9Xh.png)

What is my worry: today I only have two variations of color icon (last example), but I may have more in the future. Today, in the second case, when I want it to change the color (if it's different than the 2 options in the type) in anotrher place of the application, I have to change it directly:
[change icon color directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ePVM.png)

How can I use in the second case the same strategy I used in the first one?

Thanks!

I'd like to use the same strategy for both

Comment: Your code looks correct to me as far as I can tell. Can you post an example of your render function where you're calling your styled components? It's worth double checking that you're passing the prop correctly. Maybe adding a default case to your switch would prove that? I've done a small example of it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-elbakyan-v79l0e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, but really, when I am styling a component directly from an element in styled components (as the example you sent me), it works. It doesn't work when I am trying to access a component directly from other lib and style it through the attrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function outside your attributes and call it like.

```js
const getIconColor = (type) => {
  switch(type) {
  // .... do your logic
  }
}

//...

const Icon = styled(MaterialIcons).attrs(({theme, type}) => ({
  color: getIconColor(type)
}))
```